# Spring Batch partitioned step not running

Tags: spring-batch

I was trying to configure my first multi-threaded job. We have a master file of about 200,000 records which we need to process. I want to break the file down into 10 files and process them. The split file tasklet is working fine & it splits the bug file into 10 smaller files. I am passing the path of the files to the job in the job parameters key as "urlFilesPath" and value as"file:/**scraper** /spliturl*". I verified that the files are being read correctly in the **MultiResourcePartitioner** bean.

The master step is running in my configuration but the slave step does not run. Below is my configuration.

**Partitioner:**

```
<bean id="partitioner"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner"
    scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="#{jobParameters['urlFilesPath']}" />
</bean>
```

**MultiResourceItemReader:**

```
<bean id="multiResourceItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="#{jobParameters['urlFilesPath']}" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="urlFileItemReader" />
    <property name="strict" value="true" />
    <property name="saveState" value="false" />
</bean>
```

**FlatFileItemWriter:**

```
<bean id="urlFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
scope="step">
    <property name="lineMapper" ref="passThroughLineMapper" />      
    <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}" /> 
    <property name="saveState" value="true" /> 
</bean>
```

**Job Configuration:**

```
<batch:job id="importJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="fileSplitter" next="readURLFileRunner">
        <batch:tasklet ref="fileSplittingTasklet"
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="readURLFileRunner">
        <batch:partition step="readURLFile" partitioner="partitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

**Slave Step Configuration:**

```
<batch:step id="readURLFile">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="10">
        <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceItemReader" processor="urlFileItemProcessor"
            writer="validURLItemWriter" commit-interval="200" skip-limit="100">
            <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="java.net.MalformedURLException" />
                <batch:include class="java.net.URISyntaxException" />
                <batch:include class="java.net.UnknownHostException" />
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        </batch:chunk>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="malformedURLExceptionListener" />
            <batch:listener ref="uriSyntaxExceptionListener" />
            <batch:listener ref="unknownHostExceptionListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:end on="COMPLETED" />
</batch:step>
```

Please advise what I am doing incorrectly. I do not see the processor **urlFileItemProcessor** & the writer **validURLItemWriter** being executed.

**Update**
I followed the answer given by @dimzak. But I still do not see the step **readURLFile** being executed and loggers from the **urlFileItemProcessor** & **validURLItemWriter** are not printed to the console. The job hangs at after the following logger

```
org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate - Starting repeat context.
```

I have doubt on the way I have configured the step scope.

**StepScope Configuration**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
    <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

On the Spring forums, I have read that the **delegate** property of **multiResourceItemReader** need not be step scoped. When I removed the **scope="step"** from the **urlFileItemReader**, I get the below exception.

```
    INFO : 26 Sep 2014 00:10:58,811 - org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService  'taskExecutor'
INFO : 26 Sep 2014 00:10:59,066 - org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlFileItemReader' defined in class path resource [beansBatchService.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'stepExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.chw.hma.service.batch.jobrunner.MainJobRunner.run(MainJobRunner.java:29)
    at com.chw.hma.service.batch.jobrunner.MainJobRunner.main(MainJobRunner.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'stepExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1364)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'stepExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:78)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:85)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:143)
    ... 18 more
```

Please advise.

**Update Sep 27, 2014**

Posting the task executor etc, as advised by @dimzak

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="mySQL" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I think it's about how `resource(s)` in partitioner and in the 2 readers are set. But I have no idea what are you trying to achieve.`urlFilesPath` is like `file:folder/*` and you are trying to split each file to a slave step?... but then what `MultiResourceItemReader` is supposed to read?

Comment: @dimzak - Thanks for your comment. I have added more information in the question.

Comment: The last exception is because you removed `step=Scope` from `urlFileItemReader` so you can't read `stepExecutionContext`. I really don't understand what `multiResourceItemReader` is doing... remove it. Your main reader should be `urlFileItemReader`. Make also sure you [configured correctly your jobrepo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html) for partitioning. Your `StepScope` looks fine to me

Comment: Hmm can you also post your taskexecutor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MultiResourcePartitioner](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/MultiResourcePartitioner.html) takes `file:/scrapper/spliturl*` and splits each file like spliturl1, spliturl2, in different steps.

Afterwards, in the slave step you have to only read the specific file for this step.
So your configuration should be without a `MultiResourceItemReader`.

```
<batch:step id="readURLFile">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="10">
        <batch:chunk reader="urlFileItemReader" processor="urlFileItemProcessor"
            writer="validURLItemWriter" commit-interval="200" skip-limit="100">
            <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="java.net.MalformedURLException" />
                <batch:include class="java.net.URISyntaxException" />
                <batch:include class="java.net.UnknownHostException" />
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        </batch:chunk>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="malformedURLExceptionListener" />
            <batch:listener ref="uriSyntaxExceptionListener" />
            <batch:listener ref="unknownHostExceptionListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:end on="COMPLETED" />
</batch:step>
```